# Google Drive Authentication tab not close

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm a student, where the project assignment was using C# to implement google drive to website. Now I testing it in my Visual Studio 2015. When I start the site from my VS, it will launch an authenticate google drive. My authentication is successful, I can upload a file to Drive but the auth tab not close. Below is my code.

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var service = GoogleDriveHelper.AuthenticateOauth();
  }
}
```

**GoogleDriveHelper.cs**

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

public class GoogleDriveHelper
{
  public static DriveService AuthenticateOauth()
  {
    string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                                     DriveService.Scope.DriveFile };

    try
    {
        string  credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);

        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                                    new ClientSecrets {                           
                                      ClientId = "My-client-id",                                                                                     
                                      ClientSecret = "My-client-secret"            
                                    },                                    
                                    scopes,                                  
                                    "Users",                                                                      
                                    CancellationToken.None,                   
                                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

        DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Google Drive API Demo",
        });

        return service;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my auth tab after successfully authenticate google drive. The problem is, it did not close after authenticate.

```
http://127.0.0.1:54972/authorize/?code=4/mbNAx__wjbnjsH6xJFtsgp3V6bDoweKrI8psJPaZd5E#
```

[image: Non stop loading auth tab]

So here is the issue I try to solve:

1. Auto close auth google tab after authentication.
2. Got another error when deploy this site in IIS, authentication failed.

   Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Thanks guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by going to your Google Developer Console API and specify in your OAuth Client ID the URI where you will use the client ID.

Specify under **Authorized Javascript origins** the URI of the website (`www.mywebsiteexample.com`) and under **Authorized redirect URIs** the URI with a `/oauth2callback`.

[image]

Comment: Do I need to create this oauth2callback? Or this is from google itself?